# Static object with access to static member in the destructor

Tags: c++

I'm trying to implement the following behavior (simplified):

- There's an Object base class that anyone can derive from and there will be several instances of these.
- Anyone from anywhere can add an instance pointer to a globally accessible set of pointers to Object.
- An object should remove itself from that set (if it's in it) upon destruction.
- I only need it to work in a single thread and in a single module (no dynamic library loading etc.)

Conceptually something like this:

```
class Object {
public:
//...

~Object() { reg.erase(this);  }
static void register(Object* obj) { reg.insert(obj); }

static std::set<Object*> reg;
}
```

This is simplified, as it's not really a set but a more complicated container. As a result there are some iterators etc. involved in the register() and the destructor. I also omitted getters/setters and access control for brevity.

The problem I have with this is that it works as long as no one creates a static Object (or derived). It will then depend on the actual order of destruction of the static set and the static object (which is undefined if I'm not mistaken). I tested that it really crashes or not, depending on the order of these two. I can't(and don't want to) guarantee that no static instance of Object will be created. I also don't want to enforce user of the class to call any cleanup code etc. Object should be "self aware".

I tried to employ singleton for the set but I keep circling back to the same chicken and egg problem with statics in the destructor.

How can I either fix this or achieve the same behavior with another design (possibly without so much statics)? Maybe there's a way to ensure that a particular static will be destroyed after anything else (at least in "my" code)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be acceptable for you to enforce the user of the class to use [Construct On First Use Idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/static-init-order-on-first-use.html) for all static instances of `Object`? Then, they should always be constructed after the container which should be constructed before `main`. Static objects are destructed in reverse order of construction. Therefore all static `Object` that are constructed after the container will be destroyed first.

Quote from standard §3.6.3 / 1:

> ... If the completion of the constructor or dynamic initialization of an object with static storage
>    duration is sequenced before that of another, the completion of the destructor of the second is sequenced
>   before the initiation of the destructor of the first.

If that's not acceptable, how about adding a flag to the `Object` class:

```
class Object {
public:
    bool registered; // init to false, set to true on registration
    ~Object() { if(registered) reg.erase(this);  }
```

Then modify the destructor  of the container (use a custom delegating container or subclass if you cannot modify the current container) to set the flag `false` for each pointed object before clearing contents. This may also be possible if you wrap the container into a `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter.

Comment: > "Static objects are destructed in reverse order of construction."

Is that guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: AFAIK it's only guaranteed in a single translation unit, which is not much but sometimes enough.

Comment: I've added a quote from the standard which I construe as a guarantee. Please correct me, if I've mis-interpreted.

Comment: Basically I can't enforce anything(other than politely ask in a comment that no one will read :) ). The basic First Use Idiom doesn't delete a pointer which will freak out static analyzers and I generally like to clean my allocations. The modified version(with static in a static function) seems to handle correctly only the initialization part which is not a problem in this case. The flag solution sounds promising, but I hesitate to grow Object class as there will be quite a lot of instances (only few of which will be placed in the set). It might be an answer but I'll need to benchmark stuff.